# Unsustainable Populations Differential Equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-fractions

I need some help solving this differential equation: $\frac{\text{d}P}{\text{d}t}=kP\left(\frac{A-P}{A}\right)\left(\frac{P-m}{P}\right)$, where $P$ is the population, $t$ is time in years, $A$ is the population capacity, $m$ is the minimum population level required for sustainability, and $k$ is a constant. I think it is possible to solve this with partial fractions, but I'm unsure how.


Could you please provide full working as well.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify the right hand side:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{dP}{dt}&=kP\left( \frac{A-P}{A}\right)\left(\frac{P-m}{P} \right)\\
&=\frac{k}{A}(A-P)(P-m)
\end{aligned}
$$
which is a ODE of variables separable type:
$$
\int_{P_0}^{P_t}\frac{1}{(A-P)(P-m)}dP=\int_{t_0}^t\frac{k}{A} dt
$$
Now you use partial fractions on the left hand side to reduce the integrand to a sum of terms with logarithmic integrals:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{(A-P)(P-m)}&=\frac{U}{A-P}+\frac{V}{P-m}\\
&=\frac{U(P-m)+V(A-P)}{(A-P)(P-m)}
\end{aligned}
$$
and since the coefficient of $P$ in the numerator must be $0$ we are forced to choose $U=V$ when the numerator becomes $U(-m+A)=1$ so $U=\frac{1}{A-m}$.

So the integral on the left becomes:
$$
\int_{P_0}^{P_t}\frac{1}{(A-P)(P-m)}dP=\frac{1}{A-m}\left(\int_{P_0}^{P_t}\frac{1}{(A-P)}dP+\int_{P_0}^{P_t}\frac{1}{(P-m)}dP \right)
$$

Comment: Thank you. Could you please show how partial fractions can be used to reduce the integrand to a sum of terms?

Answer (score 0):

you have $$\frac{\text{d}P}{\text{d}t}=kP\left(\frac{A-P}{A}\right)\left(\frac{P-m}{P}\right)$$ or $$\frac{\text{d}P}{(A-P)(P-m)}=\frac kA\,dt$$ or $$\int_{P_0}^P\frac{\text{d}p}{(A-p)(p-m)}=\int_{t_0}^{t}\frac kA\,dx$$
or $$\frac{-\log (P-A)+\log (P_0-A)+\log (P-m)-\log
   (P_0-m)}{A-m}=\frac kA (t-t_0)$$
or $$\log\frac{P-m}{P-A}=\log{\frac{P_0-m}{P_0-A}}+k\frac {A-m}A (t-t_0)$$

Comment: Thank you, but what steps are taken to arrive your third equation, the fraction with logs as the numerator?

Comment: It should by now be clear to you as per the other neat answer :-)